# Replace URL using .htaccess in joomla

Tags: regex, .htaccess, joomla

Using .htacess on a Joomla website, I need to replace:

```
example.com/e-books/whatever-text-etc
```

By:

```
example.com/whatever-text-etc
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^e-books$ /(\d{4}-.*)$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it isn't working.

Help anyone?

Comment: Take off the `$`, that requires the string end. I'm not sure what your rewriting there either. The match should be `^e-books`.

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^/?e-books/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Show us full .htaccess rules.

Answer (score 1):

After researching, I've found that this works:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+e-books/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: You don't need the `\s`s and could just do that with the rewrite rule.

Comment: Which one of the \s ? Can you post the entire code in an answer?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?e-books/(\S*) /%1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]` I think would do what you are doing. Maybe make the non-whitespace required with a `+`. Should `/ebooks` with nothing else go to the root `/`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have more articles, you can create new menu item (parent) and link to your article. So, you will have URL for your article like example.com/whatever-text-etc

Then, if you want to hide this menu item in your menu bar, you just disable this option in details of menu item http://take.ms/rnTXl